# How to Define a Pivot Cache?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am writing a code that will create a pivot table based on a dynamic range. I am having issues creating the pivot cache, however. When I run the code, no error message appears, but a blank worksheet is created with no pivot table. I think the issue is the pivot cache but could be wrong. Any ideas?

I've stepped through the code several times but cannot find a bug. Everything appears to be working as it should, except no pivot table appears.

```
Option Explicit

Dim pivotSht As Worksheet
Dim dataSht As Worksheet
Dim pCache As PivotCache
Dim pTable As PivotTable
Dim pRange As Range
Dim lastR As Long
Dim lastC As Long

Public Sub buildPivot()

'CREATES PIVOT TABLE FROM OPEN ORDER BOOK DATA

'Deletes old sheet, if available, and creates a new one
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set pivotSht = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set dataSht = Worksheets("OOB")

'Defines data range in "OOB" sheet
lastR = dataSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastC = dataSht.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set pRange = dataSht.Range("D1").Resize(lastR, lastC)

'Define pivot cache
Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pRange). _
CreatePivotTable(tabledestination:=pivotSht.Cells(3, 1), _
TableName:="OpenOrderBookTable")

'Insert blank pivot table
Set pTable = pCache.CreatePivotTable _
(tabledestination:=pivotSht.Cells(3, 1), TableName:="OpenOrderBookTable")

'Insert row fields in pivot table
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OpenOrderBookTable").PivotFields("Machine")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

'Insert column fields in pivot table
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OpenOrderBookTable").PivotFields("OTD")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

'Insert data fields
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OpenOrderBookTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "OpenOrderBookTable").PivotFields("OTD"), "Count of OTD", xlCount

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OpenOrderBookTable").PivotFields("System Status")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

I expect a pivot table with my range on a new worksheet but am not getting anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try the modified code below:

```
Public Sub buildPivot()

'CREATES PIVOT TABLE FROM OPEN ORDER BOOK DATA

'Deletes old sheet, if available, and creates new one
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set pivotSht = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set dataSht = Worksheets("OOB")

'Defines data range in "OOB" sheet
With dataSht
    lastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lastC = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set pRange = .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(lastR, lastC))
End With

'Define pivot cache
Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))

'Insert blank pivot table
Set pTable = pivotSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pCache, TableDestination:=pivotSht.Range("A3"), TableName:="OpenOrderBookTable")

'Insert row fields in pivot table
With pTable.PivotFields("Machine")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

'Insert column fields in pivot table
With pTable.PivotFields("OTD")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

'Insert data fields
pTable.AddDataField pTable.PivotFields("OTD"), "Count of OTD", xlCount

With pTable.PivotFields("System Status")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The logic in the above code makes sense, but I noticed an issue when running. When typing "tabledestination", VBA does not recognize the property and leaves it lowercase. I believe that may causing my error. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @radeg it also doesn't recognize with mine, in fact, with some parameters the inteliisense will not auto-correct to Ucase, it doesn't mean it will give you an error. My code ran when I wrote it in small letters.